# How to validate URL parameters in Flask app?

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm writing a RESTful API in Flask. I can access URL parameters via the [Request Object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object). What is the best way to validate the given URL parameters?

For example:

```
/places?zip=97239 # This is a valid filter
/places?foo=bar   # This is not a valid filter, 404 response?
```

One solution is to search through `request.args` and compare each entry against a set of valid URL parameters. Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the GET parameters in a dictionary and validate it using [voluptuous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous).

For example:

```
parameters = Schema({
    Required('zip'): Coerce(int),
})
```

will accept any dictionary with a "zip" key that has a value that can be coerced to an integer (so either 1 or "1" depending on how you get the values). You can then validate it using:

```
parameters(my_get_params)  # should not raise an exception
```

Comment: I think some of you might already be using [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for models serialization then why not to use the same package to validate the query params or req body?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing validation by hand, you can use [WTForms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which, besides helping you create actual forms, [validates URL / POST parameters automatically](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#validating-forms) according to specified models.

Whether this is better will depend on your specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [flask-parameter-validation](https://github.com/Ge0rg3/flask-parameter-validation) library in order to validate within Flask. This is useful as it uses Flask features under-the-hood, handles files/forms, and implicitly converts Query parameters.

For your example, you would do the following:

```py
from flask import Flask
from typing import Optional
from flask_parameter_validation import ValidateParameters, Query

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/places", methods=["GET"])
@ValidateParameters()
def check_places(
        zip: Optional[int] = Query()
     ):
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```