# How to validate URL parameters in Flask

Tags: python, url, flask, http-post, pythonanywhere

This is my first application using Flask and Python.

I am using below URL format to send a POST request from Arduino to the flask application running on Pythonanywhere server instance.

Valid POST request: 3 URL parameters
http://voyagers.pythonanywhere.com/senddata?node=1234&lat=18.5580&lng=73.8075

I need to block the request from further processing by validating the URL in some form. I want this to secure my app from un-authenticated POST requests.

Say something like this:Anything more than 3 URL Parameters
http://voyagers.pythonanywhere.com/senddata?node=324&lat=18.5580&lng=73.8075&a=c&a=d

How can I achieve this in Flask ?

Also suggest , If there is any better way which could be used to secure application from un-authorised requests.

Comment: What connection do you see between authorisation to make a request and the number of query parameters in that request?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Authorisation here I mean , say if the the hardware device (arduino node) sends POST request consisting of more than 3 URL parameters like I have mentioned above . I don't want to handle such request(s). Say it more of error-checking !                                                    ( P.S: forgive for in-appropriate jargon ,newbie to app development)

Comment: Did you look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/29568540/3001761? Validating the input is not the same thing as securing the application, so it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. If you just mean you want to check that the only keys in the query parameter dictionary are `node`, `lat` and `lng`, *have you tried writing that?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get `flask` to validate the parameters and throw an error automatically if you are willing to switch from *URL parameters* (i.e. anything after the '?' symbol in the URL) to *path parameters* (i.e. anything that is in the `Path` HTTP header, or the part of the URL after the first '/' and abefore the '?').

Your example could look like this:

```
@app.route('/post/<int:node_id>/<float:lat>/<float:lng>', methods=['POST'])
def process_post_request(node_id, lat, lng):
    # do some work
    return your_result
```

Then you could send request to URL that would look for example like this: `http://example.com/post/1234/-11.45/21.34`

You can find more about this here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#variable-rules

For securing access you can use some of the example snippets here: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/category/authentication/

I would recommend restricting access to HTTPS only and using the basic auth if you are just playing around. This is something you can do with a simple decorator as described here: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/

You will get a prompt in your browser asking you for username and password and browser will remember it for the duration of the session. Alternatively, you can set the username and password in base64 encoded form in the `Authorization` header: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Thanks Grepe!. Above is one solution which I will try out .Is there anything similar which could be done with parameters after '?' in the URL?.     
Instead of modifying the URL as 'node_id/lat/long' ?

Comment: @balaji to my knowledge there is no URL parameter validation built into flask. you would have to write it yourself. URL parameters are pretty much free and easy to change and/or append without breaking anything... that's why they are used e.g. for tracking purposes (try clicking on almost any banner ad and look at your URL).